# Error during WebSocket handshake on AWS instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, socket.io

I created a new instance on AWS (Ubuntu) and setted up the app correctly. Everything is fine except socket.io cannot connect using websockets and that kind of creates a lot of lag on mobile phones.

I get this error:
`WebSocket connection to <url>' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`

This happens only on my EC2 instance. I'm not using any elastic beanstack. Plain simple AWS instance running expressjs server listening on port 80. I read somewhere that nginx is required to be configured. But all I did was fired node server so there is no `/etc/nginx` directory on the ubuntu instance.

I've been trying to figure this out from very long time. Please help.

Comment: What are the outbound security group configurations for EC2 instance? web-sockets required two way communication.

Comment: @kosa outbound is All Traffic (0.0.0.0)

Comment: Do you have any inbound rules on security groups? what is your overall setup? have route53? only expressjs server or anyother servers running?

Comment: @kosa inbound is just HTTP and SSH. socket.io also listens on the same port (port 80)

Comment: @kosa yes i'm using route 53 config to map it to a domain. Only express server is running

Comment: @kosa I'm also using elastic IP address. I tried to put elastic IP address in socket.io connection from client but it's still exact same error

Comment: Ok, if I understand correctly, only socket.io requests are failing, other requests like page content successful, is that correct?

Comment: @kosa yes. as of now only websocket requests are failing. socket.io falls back to ajax then, but i'll like to fix this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149634/discussion-between-kosa-and-mehulmpt).

Comment: how do you start your app from ec2 ? please post the code that is making the socket and connection, and how server is run

Comment: @mehulmpt Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @That1Guy I honestly don't remember, my infrastructure currently is on DigitalOcean

Comment: @mehulmpt Thanks for getting back to me - I moved mine to Digital Ocean as well, but I'm experiencing the same problem. I'm going to have to table this for a while. Please let me know if something comes to you. Thanks again.